# Remove Duplicate names from a column 1 based on other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge and align in center column 1 to remove duplicate entries of the same name but its not working for me.

So far I tried to group them based on other 2 columns and loc, but it disturbs the formatting.

[Result I am getting!! <--image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ37p.png)

So far, I have tried below:

```py
excel_data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ZDQT2846\Documents\Data\GOLD ADD NOTES Template.xlsx', sheet_name='New Order')
    df_count=(excel_data.groupby(['Order Delivery Manager','Customer Name']).size()).to_frame()
df_count.rename(columns = {'Order Delivery Manager':'Order Delivery Manager', 
                           'Customer Name':'Customer Name', 0:'Count'}, 
                inplace = True)
```

It gives me the desired result but it only has 1 column 'Count' when I check for dataframe.columns.

and when I do index reset via below, this uniqueness goes away.

```
df_new = df_count.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Can you guys please help.

FYI, here is how the data should look:

[Expected Result <--Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTCNO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post the expected output as text instead of linking to an external location

Comment: I have tried but its not in the correct format, thus will confuse everyone

Comment: The information in your comment does not help as it has a different set of names. In your input, Join David has 3 customers - what should be Join David's customer in the output, where there is only 1 row for each Manager

Comment: yeah there should be 1 row for the duplicate Manager's name.

Comment: And what value should it contain?

Comment: Please check my initial post, I have updated 2 images, of what I am getting and what I am expecting. Thanks :)